# Creating an object of class in MVC error! c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC, But i have created a class that in the Model folder for data like so:

```
public class Book
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string BookName { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public string ISBN { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to create an object of this Book Model but I keep getting this error:

> The type or namespace name 'Book' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly

here is how I am creating the `Book` object in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Test()
        {
            Book book = new Book();
        }
```

I think I might might be missing `using System.something` but can anybody help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What namespace is the class Book in? If it's in the namespace Models, add a:

using Model;

At the top of the file where you're trying to create the Book instance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `Book.cs` file or whatever the file that contains `Book` class,then look at the  namespace of your class and then import it with a *using* directive in your controller.

Also you can use tools like `ReSharper`, it will find the relevant namespace automatically and suggest you to import it when you type the class name.

Comment: Thank you.Is resharp an extension? should should I just download it and install it?